# Forwarding wifi traffic to wired pc

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, wireshark, sniffing

I'm trying to play around with Wireshark on my home network, and was wondering if there is a way to create a new connection on my PC that receives all wifi packets on the network. The PC is a *wired* Windows 7 machine, and I'm using DD-WRT on an Asus RT-N16 router. I'm not trying to hack anything, I have full admin access to the router itself.

My searching has led me to articles about client bridges and repeater bridges, but none of them seemed to apply entirely to my situation. I'd like to continue using my standard wifi connection, but make my PC act as a repeater that receives all wifi traffic. Again, the PC has no wireless connection.

I've used tcpdump which is installed on the router itself, but I'd be more comfortable analyzing the packets in Windows, as I'm trying to learn Wireshark.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can open a tcpdump file in wireshark, so the capture could be done on the router and then you could analyse it using wireshark on your desktop.  For details about setting tcpdump to capture for wireshark see [the wireshark manual](http://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/AppToolstcpdump.html)